# Excel-VBA: is there a VBA command that reads it's own line number

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel 2016 VBA code has rare occasions of fatal errors (e.g. loss of variable or reference values).

It sends mail/text then.
I'm looking for a way to state in which module and code line the problem occurred.

Is there a VBA command that can read the module name and the line number?
...without hard-coding the module and function/sub name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Erl` as long as you have added line numbers to the code.

Comment: Basic code with line numbers - now there's a trip down memory lane!

Comment: @YowE3K I saw someone using `Gosub` the other day - that was a blast from the past!

Comment: If the OP really starts using code numbers and `Erl` to report an error line through email this would be one of the best job defences I have seen so far.  Still, it would be rather useless, if the project is with many multiple modules.

Comment: not your fault but line numbers are not really wanted :-)

and yep, I remember my times with the Commodore neck roll thingy.

Comment: @JoePhi Can't really report line numbers if there are no line numbers!

Answer (score 1):

My idea of best case scenario for emailing fatal errors:

- Save all the user's input in a class variable. In case of error, mail the information to yourself plus the type of the error.
- This should be enough to replicate and fix.

Concerning a way to get the module name without hardcoding - there is no such way. But using a hardcoded variable for the name is not that difficult - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/InsertProcedureNames.aspx

Comment: yes, understood. I wanted something that compensates for missing discipline, i.e. always hard-code constants with the module, function name, internal error number & text...

Comment: @JoePhi - I think that you may get the constant names written for you automatically from the article in my post.

Comment: thumb up! not tried yet but looks promising. Danke!